# No Thumbnails in posting Kaltura's Videos

Tags: wordpress, video, thumbnails, video-thumbnails, kaltura

I am using the Kaltura's All i One Video Plugin in WordPress. Whenver, I post a video using Kaltura, whether it is embeded or through the Plug-in Content, The Post doesn't fetch it's thumbnail. If i use youtube or any other video link the thumbnail load corrctly.

Comment: Try to inspect the img element on the page and provide the URL to the thumbnail, this will be easier to troubleshoot with

Answer (score 0):

Is the thumb generate properly on Kaltura? Can you see it in the kmc?

Comment: ok, It was just to check if it were a Kaltura problem or a WordPress problem. So your issue is in WordPress somewhere.

Comment: My friend, could you pleasse elaborate how the issue is in the WordPress. The Wordpress is loading thumbnails for the youtube embeded and links. For Kaltura based media, The thumbnails are shown until we are watching the video in the Media library, but as we insert the video in the post the thumnail disappers, and a grey box is inserted in the post. written "The player goes here" in in.